# React TypeScript Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'Object constructor'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to both React and TypeScript so there might be something obvious that I have missed. I'm trying to do the following:

```
const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, {
    loaded: this.state.loaded
});
```

I get this error in my `.tsx` file: `Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'Object constructor'.`

Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959372/property-assign-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor) and tried:

```
const props = (<any>Object).assign({}, this.props, {
    loaded: this.state.loaded
});
```

Gave me this error: `Property 'any' does not exist on type 'JXS.IntrinsicElements'.`

I also tried this which returned `Unexpected modifier` for declare.

```
declare interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign(target: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: That's kinda weird. Can you give a little more context? E.g. the Component you're using it and also maybe your `tsconfig`? Because there should be no issue with you first code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.assign` is a `es6` feature so you need to target `es6`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "target": "es6",
        ...
    }
}
```

If you can't target `es6` but still know for sure that your code will run in environments that do support new `es6` features then you can use the lib:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "target": "es5", // for example
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES6", "ScriptHost"],
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to add this funtionality yourself.
You'll need to add the definitions (copied from the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4461)):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
    assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V;
    assign<T, U, V, W>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V, source3: W): T & U & V & W;
    assign(target: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
}
```

And then [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

As for the casting part that you tried, you can't use this form of casting inside `tsx` files, you need to do this:

```
const props = (Object as any).assign({}, this.props, {
    loaded: this.state.loaded
});
```

Because in `tsx` files the compiler thinks that `<any>` as an html/react element.