# transform array to dynamic object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to transform the following array which is dynamic to an dynamic object

e.g.

let

```
array=[{"MyFirstValue":"1"},{MySecondvalue:"2"}]
```

I would like to convert it ti an dynamic object

like

```
let newobject={MyFirstValue:"1",MySecondvalue:"2" }
```

The dynamic object here is that depending upon the numbers of values in the array the newobject should be able to transform 
e.g.

if the array value changes =

```
array=[{"MyFirstValue":"1"},{MySecondvalue:"2"},{MyThirdValue:"2"}]
```

The newobject should transform to

```
newobject={MyFirstValue:"1",MySecondvalue:"2",MyThirdValue:"2" }
```

I tried using array.map and pushing the value but could not set the key property

It is like reducing the reducing the array to an object. I am not sure if i can use reduce.

Comment: you need at least different keys ...?

Comment: You need different keys or call like let newobject={"1","2" }

Comment: what's wrong with this `[{"key":"1"},{key:"2"}]` **object**?

Comment: this is impossible unless you have different keys. using `key` for two entries in a map is a collision

Comment: what is a "dynamic object" for you exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
let newobject= array.reduce((x,y)=> ({...x,...y}), {});
```

```js
let array=[{"MyFirstValue":"1"},{MySecondvalue:"2"}]

let newobject= array.reduce((x,y)=> ({...x,...y}), {});

console.log(newobject);
```

Comment: This way will introduce bugs if either of your objects have the same key (the second object's value will override the first's).  Is it a good idea to make the assumption that both objects have completely unique keys?

Comment: @CoryKleiser Uno: OP in first question version use two same keys, but he correct this and made unique keys. Secundo: OP doesn't describe what kind of result he expect in case when keys are not unique (e.g. may be if he will interested on that case then he want to get last value of non unique key in array... ) so this means that non-unique keys case is out of the scope of OP question.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense; still, I doubt OP wants to trivially throw away values based on the order of objects in the array. Spanish 101 lesson: *first* in Spanish is *primero*  :)

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this using `Object.assign` assuming your keys are unique.

```js
const array = [{"key1":"1"}, {"key2":"2"}];

const newObject = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: I am using typescript and get this error Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: There is some discussion about how to handle this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959372/property-assign-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to have unique keys in your object. Also, you should **not** expect all your objects to have 100% unique keys. Instead of having `{key: 1, key: 2}`, why not have the property `key` be an array of values; `{key: [1, 2]}`. I would use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve this.

```js
const array = [{"key":"1", other: 'FOO'},{key:"2", dynamic: 'BAR', other: 'BAZ'}]

const object = array.reduce((initial, value) => {
  Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
    if(initial[key]) initial[key].push(value[key])
    else initial[key] = [value[key]]
  })
  return initial;
}, {})

console.log(object)
```

Comment: plus 1 for Spanish lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

Using ES5:

```js
var input = [{"MyFirstValue":"1"},{MySecondvalue:"2"},{MyThirdValue:"2"}];

var output = Object.assign.apply({}, input);

console.log(output);
```