# TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular8

I have a file which contains static data as **QRCategories** and want to send the data as an observable.

The service sending the data is

```
public qrCodeCategoriesList(): Observable<QRCategoryListResponse> {
    return of (QRCategories);
  }
```

It is used in component as:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.qrCategoryService.qrCodeCategoriesList().subscribe(
     res => {
       this.qrCategories = res;
     }, error => {
       console.log(error);
     }
   );
  }
```

which works fine but gives an error  **Property 'assign' does not exist on type** in the below line at different component :

```
  const formData: RegisterData = this.registerForm.value;
  const password2 =   {password2: formData.password1};
  const data = Object.assign({}, formData, password2);
```

qr-category.ts

```
import {QRCategoryListResponse} from '../models/qr/qr-category.model';

export const QRCategories: QRCategoryListResponse = {
  count: 10,
  next: null,
  previous: null,
  results: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Website URL',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Google Maps',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'PDF',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Image',
    }
   ]};
```

Comment: Can you share your stackblitz @Ayushi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959372/property-assign-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try using following :

```
const data=(<any>Object).assign(formData, password2)
```

or

```
data={...formData,...password2};
```

Make sure this will copy by reference nested objects, so use deep copy instead with library like Lodash, or :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someData));
```